# Where is the transmit power of antenna in RF circuit schematic calculated?

Tags: power, antenna, radio, transmitter

I want to measure the transmit power of my AM modulated RF circuit. Below is the RF circuit from LTSpice. Should the power be calculated at nodes R5 or C3? Which node can serve as an antenna? The reason for my question is about the power calculation at nodes C3 and R5. C3 is very high but R5 is low. How can I get rid of this difference when an antenna should transmit?

[image: circuit]

Comment: How relevant is the power into R5 given that it doesn't appear to represent an antenna very much at all.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi, I made a loop antenna, so I can ground it easily into the circuit. I mean I would prefer the power of the C3 instead of R5. Can I set the antenna at C3 parallel? By the way, I have finally obtained an oscillator with 100MHz bandwidth. It is nice now with measurements.

Comment: 100 MHz? I don't think so, not with that value tank. A loop antenna doesn't need a ground. C3 doesn't have any power. All these things are heavily confusing me.

Comment: @Andyaka I have just bought an oscillator externally. It has nothing with the circuit above.

Comment: Why are you mentioning it? Is it relevant to your question?

Comment: @Andyaka I wanted just to mention that I am well upgraded to measure the frequencies in RF circuits.

Comment: I think what @Andyaka is saying is that 10 ohms does not represent a real antenna. Additionally, C3 is a DC block cap (?) and therefore should essentially be 0 ohms at RF - therefore, it shouldn't have any power. An oscillator isn't going to help you measure RF. There's a lot more to RF measurements than an oscillator.

Comment: @Jason Where should the antenna be set on, then? The power comes from the circuit. How to measure power of antenna? Say, I know the impedance of it. Maybe 10 ohms or 50 ohms. Can LTSpice help me out?

Comment: They mean oscilloscope, not oscillator.

Comment: Thank you @GodJihyo. I should have probably been able to guess that.

Comment: @GodJihyo Thanks for the correction. I was surprised at the reaction of the public here, why they humble my pride. Yes, the corrected word is "oscilloscope".

Comment: @lastime to answer your question about impedance - it depends on your antenna. For example, googling "dipole impedance" you'll find that its in the 75 ohm ball park. I typically work in much higher frequencies and 50 ohms is typically the impedance of an antenna.

Comment: @Jason How can I measure the power of a transmitting antenna when it has its activity in RF circuit? Is a simulation software reliable for that or do I need an external tool to measure it? For example there are SWR meters for antennas. It measures impedance and the frequencies of antennas. Do you mean that it is impossible to get around this problem by given trivial methods? I have for example a 50 ohm antenna. What then?

Comment: To measure the RF power of a transmitting antenna, you need an RF power meter or a good, calibrated receiver.  You then need to account for range/distance effects, antenna pattern, etc.

Comment: Dear lastime:  Spice is fine for determining the transmit power into your antenna, as long as you have a good circuit level model of the antenna.  Spice will not help you find a circuit model of the antenna, though.  For that, you need an electromagnetic simulator.  In your circuit, it looks like you have modeled your antenna as the resistor, R5.   This may be an adequate model, or maybe it is not so good.  If R5 is good enough, then you can find the power dissipated in R5 from  Spice, and that is the transmitted power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a video on internet. It demonstrates a long distance radio transmitter with schematics. The antenna is on the label "ANT". It is similar to your RF circuit.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtfEhW0PRj0